# create file and save to it using memorystream

Tags: c#, memorystream

How can i create a file and write to it using the memory stream?
I need to use the memorystream to prevent other threads from trying to access the file.

The data i'm trying to save to a file is html.

How can this be done?

Comment: So why not save the data directly to memory stream?

Comment: What do ya mean? I want the data to be saved in a file.

Comment: Will the file be potentially modified after its creation?

Comment: No it will be potentially read.

Comment: Then it's safe to read it from multiple threads.

Comment: Somehow it's not because i can see the logs with a lot of errors about 'cannot access the file because its being used by another proces'.

Comment: Are you sure you are opening the file in read mode?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(Presuming you mean how to copy a file's content to a memory stream)

If you are using framework 4:

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

using var fileStream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
```

Comment: The data that is comming in, comes from a webbrouwser control. The html content of a website. That will be passed to a string and from there saved to a file. But before that, i do some string operations removing things that don't need to be saved like Flash en javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Here are code to create file

```
byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is a sample string");
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
ms.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
ms.Close();
```